# connection refused while trying to connect Golang to mssql server using docker

Tags: mysql, docker, go, connection-refused

I am trying to connect my golang program to a mssql server that I run on a container using docker. the golang is also running on a docker container. the go script seems to be able to successfully connect to the database, but can't perform any operation on it. So,

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql","SA:YourStrong!Passw0rd@tcp(127.0.0.1:1433)/")

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer db.Close()
fmt.Println("Success open database")
```

This prints out the "success open database", however the next portion of the code  throws a panic,

```
_,err = db.Exec("CREATE DATABASE currency1")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Success CREATE database")
```

After using docker to build and run it, this is what I got

```
GO MYSQL START
Success open database
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1433: getsockopt: connection refused
```

This is the command I used to run the `mssql` database:

```
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong!Passw0rd' -e 'MSSQL_PID=Express' -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should `Ping()` the database when you connected it.

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql","SA:YourStrong!Passw0rd@tcp(127.0.0.1:1433)/")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := db.Ping();err!=nil{
    panic(err)
}

defer db.Close()
fmt.Println("Success open database")
```

`Open()` doesn't mean connected the database correctly.

The otherwise, like Dhama had said, your database host is wrong.
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first you should understand how networking in docker works. Every running container will treated as single virtual node. They have their own IP to connect to each other. In your case, there will 2 running container, 1 for Go and 1 for SQLServer. So there is Go container wanted to connect to SQLServer container. The address `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` means it's for it self(a loopback address). To connect it you can use the container name as the address (because IP is randomly assigned). Actually it converted to IP, docker doing this for you. Based on your docker run above, it should be `sql1`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You also need to `docker network create` a network (default options is fine) and `docker run --net` both containers on that network.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. However, I am still having difficulties as it does not seem to work. I used "docker create network my-net". then of course add the line --network=my-net to both my docker run commands. Docker did detect both containers as the command "docker inspect my-net" shows both containers. however, when I used docker to run both the sql and go script, no panic was thrown.  it's just "GO MYSQL START
Success open database". P.S. I also changed my go script to ==> db, err := sql.Open("mysql","SA:YourStrong!Passw0rd@tcp(sql1.my-net:1433)/")

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue otherway around from docker container to local mysql server, the trick was to comment `bind-address` in `my.cnf`. Usually its bind only to the loopback address, and refuse connection from outside including docker network. You can give a try to create a `my.cnf` like below and mount it to mysql config via `volume(-v)`.

> ```
> #bind-address                   = 127.0.0.1
> ```